# How to print the specific in an HTML file using golang?

Tags: html, go, templates, go-templates

In this code, I want to use and give a specific detail in the HTML file like heading or price.

The problem is that, there are multiple headings and prices and when I print the specific one, it prints the specific data successfully but I don't know how to use it in an HTML file to print the specific data there. All I know about GOHTML is `{{.Heading}}` but it does not work. Is there any other way?

```
package main

import "net/http"

type Details struct {
    Heading string
    Price   string
}

var Detail = []Details{
    {
        Heading: "First Cloth",
        Price:   "$59",
    },
    {
        Heading: "Second Cloth",
        Price:   "$49",
    },
}

func Main(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    HomeTmpl.Execute(w, Detail)
    // fmt.Println(Detail[1].Heading) // For specific data
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the builtin `index` template function to get an element from a slice:

```
{{ (index . 1).Heading }}
```

Testing it:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{ (index . 1).Heading }}`))
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, Detail); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b9Bwhb7EpOK)):

```
Second Cloth
```

Comment: I executed the template and put `{{ (index . 1).Heading }}` in the HTML file but it printed the whole HTML code. Although I am trying to show it in the browser.

Comment: Does your template render a compelte HTML documet? Does it start with `<html>`? Also do check the error returned by `Template.Execute()`.

Comment: It worked. I changed `os.Stdout` with `w`and rendered it in the HTML file. Thank you icza!

Comment: @SumbaloDi Yes, `os.Stdout` was just to test / demonstrate that it works. In HTTP handlers you have to use `w` to write to the HTTP response.